# Java - Scanner does not remove all of the desired objects

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make some kind of 'Evil Hangman game' (nifty Stanford CS exercises). The purpose of the game is to 'cheat' by removing as many possible word solutions as possible so the user cannot guess before the very end.

I have made a loop (below) which seems to remove many of the words possible words but for some reason it does not remove all of them. The input is a dictionary.txt file which contains about 120K words.

When I 'guess' the letter "a" it will take away roughly 60-70% of the words with "a" in them (estimate based on comparisons between the output with the first couple of words in the txt file)

```
File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
    Scanner textScan = new Scanner(file);

     List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

     while ( textScan.hasNext() )
        {
            word = textScan.next();
            wordList.add(word);

        }
     System.out.println("The ArrayList has " + wordList.size() + " objects stored in it.");


     Scanner textScan1 = new Scanner(file);

    for(int i = 0; i <= guessNumber; i++)

    {   
        Collections.sort(wordList);

        System.out.println("Type in your guess as a letter ");
        String guess = keyboard.next();
        guess = guess.toLowerCase();

     while ( textScan1.hasNext() )
    {
        String word1 = textScan1.next();
        if (wordLength != word1.length() && word1.contains(guess))
            {
            wordList.remove(word1);
            }


    }
    }
```

I am aware that my code is a bit messy at this point, I am trying to improve everything about my programming so all feedback is greatly appreciated! I have the feeling that I am including stuff that does not have to be there and so on.

I will post the whole code below in case that helps:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;




public class EvilHangman 

{


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // declaring variables
    int wordLength;
    int guessNumber;


    // initiate the scanner
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );




    // introduction and prompting the user for word length

    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman. Let's play! ");
    System.out.println("Please enter the desired word length: ");
    wordLength = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(wordLength < 0 || wordLength > 26)
    {
        System.out.println("This is not a valid word length. ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired word length: ");
        wordLength = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    // prompt the user for number of guesses 

    System.out.println("How many guesses do you want to have? ");
    guessNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(guessNumber < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Number of guesses has to be a postive integer. ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired number of guesses: ");
        guessNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
    }


    // count the number of words with the specified length

    /* int wordCount = 0;
    String word = null;
    while ( textScan.hasNext() )
    {
        word = textScan.next();
        if (word.length() == wordLength)
            {
            wordCount++;
            }


    }
    */


    // prompts the user whether he/she wants a running count of word length - using next() instead of nextLine() to clear buffer

    /* System.out.println("Do you want a running total of number of words remaining? ");
    String runningTotal = keyboard.next();

    if (runningTotal.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        System.out.println("Words with that length: " + wordCount);
    */  

    // create a list (array) of all the words that matches the input length
    String word = null;


    File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
    Scanner textScan = new Scanner(file);

     List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

     while ( textScan.hasNext() )
        {
            word = textScan.next();
            wordList.add(word);

        }
     System.out.println("The ArrayList has " + wordList.size() + " objects stored in it.");


     Scanner textScan1 = new Scanner(file);

    for(int i = 0; i <= guessNumber; i++)

    {   
        Collections.sort(wordList);

        System.out.println("Type in your guess as a letter ");
        String guess = keyboard.next();
        guess = guess.toLowerCase();

     while ( textScan1.hasNext() )
    {
        String word1 = textScan1.next();
        if (wordLength != word1.length() && word1.contains(guess))
            {
            wordList.remove(word1);
            }


    }
    }

    System.out.println("The ArrayList has " + wordList.size() + " objects stored in it.");
    System.out.println(wordList);
```

Comment: Are all the words in the dictionary lower case? If so, this line `guess = guess.toLowerCase();` maybe the problem since you're only checking for lower case letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out it had to do with the scanner. It had to be initiated inside the loop

```
for(int i = 1; i <= guessNumber; i++)

    {   
        Scanner textScan2 = new Scanner(file1);         
        System.out.println("Type in your guess as a letter ");
        String guess = keyboard.next();
        //System.out.print(guess);

     while ( textScan2.hasNext() )
    {

         String word1 = textScan2.next();
        if (wordLength != word1.length() || (word1.contains(guess)))
            {
            wordList.remove(word1);
            }





    }
    }
```